# Does a continuous function preserve metrizability?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, continuity, metrizability

This is problem 6.1.8 of S. Morris's "Topology without Tears":

Let $f$ be a continuous mapping of a metrizable space $(X,\tau)$ onto a topological space $(Y,\tau_1)$.  Is $(Y, \tau_1)$ necessarily metrizable?

My Solution (by Counterexample):

Let $X$ be the Real line with the standard Euclidean topology.  Clearly, $f$ is metrizable.

Let $Y = \{0,1\}$ with the indiscrete topology, i.e., $\tau_1 = \{\emptyset, \{0,1\}\}$.  An indiscrete space with at least two points is not metrizable

Define $f$ as follows:

$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
 0&\text{if}\, x\in \mathbb{Q}\\
 1&\text{if}\, x\in \mathbb{I}
\end{cases}
$

So, every open interval in $\mathbb{R}$ maps to $\{0,1\}$, and the inverse image of $\{0,1\}$ is $\mathbb{R}$.  So, $f$ maps open sets to open sets.

Therefore, $f$ is a continuous function from a metrizable space to a non-metrizable space.

Comment: You mean "$\{0,1\}$ with antidiscrete topology". Yes, you're counterexample is correct.

Comment: In the definition of $f$, you mean $\mathbb I\setminus \mathbb Q$, I take it.   It is also called the trivial topology,  btw.  Oh, $\mathbb I$ means irrational.   I got it.

Comment: Note that *any* surjective map $\Bbb R\to \{0,1\}$ will do, since a map to an indiscrete space is *always* continuous.

Comment: Oops!  I typed "discrete" for indiscrete in the first instance.  Thank you for the correction!

Comment: You can also get examples using the discrete topology. Let Y be any non-metrisable space, X the same set with the discrete topology and f the identity mapping from X to Y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of the word *discrete* in *"Let $Y=\{0,1\}$ with the discrete topology"* is the opposite of what you mean.

Also, *"So, $f$  maps open sets to open sets."* is not what defines the continuity of $f$. You have to check that $f^{-1}$ maps open sets to open sets (which you did).

All in all, the counterexample is correct.

Comment: The OP *also* checked that $f$ maps open sets to open sets (in other words that the map is open).  A much simpler map could also have been used that was not open.  Still, it's a fine counterexample, and even a counterexample to the weaker statement that every *open* continuous map preserves metrizability.

Comment: Thanks!  I fixed the typo on "discrete" to "indiscrete".  Also, I appreciate your pointing out that the key thing to check is the inverse map.